# Reducción de Matríz hacia atras método Gauss Jordan en OCTAVE

Tags: octave

tengo que reducir una matriz en este caso de 3x3 hacia atrás y no me la reduce dejándome solo los valores de la diagonal principal.

Esto es en el programa OCTAVE(similar al MATLAB). Alguna ayuda? Se agradece!

Adjunto el código

```
    A=[-1 -2 2;1 1 -1;1 2 -1];
N=length(A)
b=[-1;1;2];

 
for i=N-1:-1:1
 
 x(N)=b(N)/A(N,N);
 S=0;
 
   for j=i+1:N      
   S=S+A(i,j)*x(j);
  end
  x(i)=(b(i)-S)/A(i,i);
``  end
```

Comment: básicamente con el primer for recorro de abajo hacia arriba(dado que es voy hacia atrás)y con el segundo recorro las columnas(empezando de abajo hacia arriba tambien,por eso puse que j empieza en i+1).No sé por qué no me toma todo el código,lo adjunto acá: A=[-1 -2 2;1 1 -1;1 2 -1];
N=length(A)
b=[-1;1;2];

 
for i=N-1:-1:1
 
 x(N)=b(N)/A(N,N);
 S=0;
 
   for j=i+1:N      
   S=S+A(i,j)*x(j);
  end
  x(i)=(b(i)-S)/A(i,i);
``  end

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Ese gran comentario posiblemente contiene aclaraciones e info adicional que podrías añadir en la pregunta. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante 
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). 
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!